# How do you encode that different arrows have the same underlying operation in a category?

Tags: category-theory

As an exercise I'm trying to express subjects I'm interested in, into categorical languages.

While trying to represent chess, I noticed a relationship arrows can have, that I'd like to have a definition of, or a name for.

To model chess I decided to represent the board states as objects, and the moves between the states by arrows. When trying to name those arrows, I decided to name them after the move they represented. But then different arrows get the same name.

For example in the following two openings:

Nf3 Nc6

e4 Nc6

If I want to think of these move names as composition of arrows, then the Nc6 refers to two different arrows. Because, the starting board state before the black knight move is different, because white's opening was different.

In an attempt to understand this I considered natural numbers.

I splayed them out as an abstract category:

$0 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 3  \rightarrow \ldots$

And tried to explain how all the arrows were "really" +1.

My best idea was to consider a Functor from this category to a one object category N, containing the morphisms $1, 2, 3, \ldots$ whose composition is just addition.

To define the functor, each number object goes to N, Each arrow between adjacent numbers goes to 1, each composition of adjacent pairs of arrows goes to two, etc.

Now "an arrow is 1" means there's a Functor *to* 1.

But this explanation doesn't work for chess, because all the moves aren't always legal, so you can't make a chess monoid in the same manner that you can make the abstract Natural number category into a monoid.

So what's the right way to encode that different arrows in chess correspond to the same move? Is my Functor for Natural numbers the correct notion for this in their special case? Is there a name for what it is I'm trying to do?

Edit:
Here's a simpler category with the roadblock I care about.

Imagine three objects, -1, 0, 1. With two arrows between -1 and 0, and two between 0 and 1. [image: Hasse Diagram]

Consider the category freely generated by this diagram. If I tried naming the generating arrows as follows: $R_0 : -1 \rightarrow 0$, $R_1 : 0 \rightarrow 1$, $L_0 : 1 \rightarrow 0$, $L_{-1} : 0 \rightarrow -1$. Then compositions are sequences of arrows that can't have more than two L's, or R's in a row. An example composition: $L_0 L_{-1} R_{0} L_{-1} R_{0} R_{1}$.

I seem to be able to think of this "as if", I have a pebble on a three square board. With the "rules" move left, and move right, which can be carried out provided the pebble doesn't fall off the board. But "Left" refers to two different arrows, and I don't know how to wrap this up in a functor in the same way I did for the natural numbers.

For more context, here is the sort of math I'm trying to understand, from the following website(https://alpof.wordpress.com/2019/10/05/networks-in-transformational-music-theory-4/):
[image: Diagram of chord relations]

I'm trying to figure out how to "Color the arrows" formally.

Comment: As a general rule, when trying to understand an abstract definition or field X, it's wise to start by studying the standard/usual examples considered in that field. But sometimes these examples are outside my comfort zone, and I'm tempted to understand X by studying how X applies to a less standard example Y that I know well from other studies (say the integers, or chess). But in those cases, it's **much** better to start with "*what phenomena do standard tools of X model when applied to Y*", instead of "*how can I model phenomena of interest to students of Y using the terminology of X?*". 1/

Comment: This question could be much easier to answer if you already explored the former question about your newly defined chess category $C$ and number category $N$. You'd be able to describe when two objects are isomorphic in $C$/$N$, when is an arrow $f$ a monomorphism in $C$/$N$, how do I compute their compositions and their equality, can there an initial/terminal object, and most importantly "are my categories even well-defined categories in the first place?", which I'm not convinced of. Even then, sometimes a particular model is not an appropriate setting to express some phenomenon of interest 2/

Comment: and one needs to come up with another model. The issue is that, even if the definitional issues were resolved,  "I cooked up a random category, now how do I define *phenomenon of interest in chess* in it?" and "How to cook up a category which can model *phenomenon of interest in chess*?" both seem way too open-ended; worst of all, even if somebody answers them, that will probably not help you with your actual goal of understanding category theory better by expressing subjects you're interested via categorial language. (This is meant to give an idea of likely answers, not to discourage.) 3/3

Comment: Well, I'm definitely interested in "how these two arrows are an example of the same thing", which is why I provided the natural number example.

Comment: I have a third example in mind from transformational music theory, where the objects are major and minor chords, and the arrows between them are how they change due to elements of the PLR group, Where P, L, and R are different methods of changing between the chords. There is going to be a P arrow for each chord, for example. But this example doesn't capture "you can't apply this move now" because you can always apply the transforms. That's why I shared the abstract Natural number category instead.

Comment: @Z.A.K. Your advice is very good, I'll keep it in mind when working with unfamiliar subjects, now and in the future.

Comment: You don’t need any fancy tricks to answer this. The arrows have a different source and target and are therefore different. That they have ‘the same underlying operation’ could perhaps be construed as an instance of a local isomorphism of hom sets or through some kind of ‘knight moves’ natural transformation, I don’t know - that’s more interesting - but technically everything is fine and already distinguished